# Property of index of a subgroup with slightly different assumptions

Tags: abstract-algebra

One of the properties of subgroups' indexes is:

If $K<H<G$ ($H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is a subgroup of $H$), then
$$|G:K| = |G:H| |H:K|.$$

My question is: what do we have to change when our assumptions are quite different, I mean $K,H<G$ ($K$ and $H$ are simply subgroups of $G$, without any relationship beetwen $K$ and $H$)?

Comment: I don't think there is any meaningful connection. I mean you can observe $H\cap K$ and use what you already know.

Comment: Thank you very much